# How to find a 'nontrivial' open cover of an arbitrary metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Give a 'nontrivial' open cover of an arbitrary metric space. 
This question is from topology metric spaces by S. Kumaresan (page 82 excercise 4.1.7). I don't have any idea what i have to do.

Comment: What is the definition of 'nontrivial'?

Answer (score 2):

An open cover of a metric space $X$ is a collection of open subsets $(U_i)_i$ such that $X = \bigcup_i U_i$. As $X$ is an open set, the cover $\{X\}$ of $X$ is welldefined. Any cover containing $X$ as one of the open subsets is considered to be trivial. Hence you are asked to find a cover consisting purely of proper open subsets. Can you give such a cover?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the family of all the open subsets of $X$, $\tau = \{ U \subseteq X :\, U \textrm{ is open in } X\}$. Surely $\tau$ is an open cover of $X$, but also, $\{X\}$ is an open cover of $X$. So, this two open covers can be considered *trivial*, right? (Yeah, that exercise is very weird).

Just an idea: can you prove that
$$\mathcal O_r := \{ B(x,r) :\, x \in X \} \quad \textrm{for some $r \in \mathbb R^+$}$$
is an open cover of $X$?

Comment: Why that $r\in \Bbb R^+$ bit?

Comment: How can be modified? Enlighten me.

Comment: Why not pick an $\varepsilon > 0$?

Comment: A fixed radius for all the balls?

Comment: Exactly. I think a cover by $\varepsilon$-balls is *the* nontrivial standard cover of a metric space, isn’t it?

Comment: Thanks for the insight!